# Confirmation that the message was sent to the CAN bus using socketCAN

Tags: c, sockets, can-bus, socketcan, recvmsg

I would like to confirm that my message has been saved on the CAN bus with socketCAN library.
The socketCAN documentation describes this possibility when using the recvmsg() function, I have problems with its implementation.

The function I want to achieve is to confirm that my message won the arbitration process.

Comment: Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think mentioning `recvmsg(2)` you refer to the following paragraph of the SocketCAN docs:

```
MSG_CONFIRM: set when the frame was sent via the socket it is received on.
      This flag can be interpreted as a 'transmission confirmation' when the
      CAN driver supports the echo of frames on driver level, see 3.2 and 6.2.
      In order to receive such messages, CAN_RAW_RECV_OWN_MSGS must be set.
```

The key words here are *"when the
      CAN driver supports the echo of frames on driver level"*, so you have to ensure that first. Next, you need to enable the corresponding flags. **Finally**, such confirmation has nothing to do with *arbitration*. When a frame looses arbitration, the controller tries to re-transmit it as soon as the bus becomes free.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the command "candump can0/can1" on your PC, it will shows the CAN packet received on given CAN interface.

```
Usage: candump [options] <CAN interface>+
  (use CTRL-C to terminate candump)

Options: -t <type>   (timestamp: (a)bsolute/(d)elta/(z)ero/(A)bsolute w date)
         -c          (increment color mode level)
         -i          (binary output - may exceed 80 chars/line)
         -a          (enable additional ASCII output)
     -b <can>    (bridge mode - send received frames to <can>)
     -B <can>    (bridge mode - like '-b' with disabled loopback)
     -u <usecs>  (delay bridge forwarding by <usecs> microseconds)
     -l          (log CAN-frames into file. Sets '-s 2' by default)
     -L          (use log file format on stdout)
     -n <count>  (terminate after receiption of <count> CAN frames)
     -r <size>   (set socket receive buffer to <size>)
```